# Spaced keys in multi level JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am fairly new to `JSON` and `JavaScrip`t. I am figuring out how to access the value in "**4. close**" in the `JSON` output I received from `Alpha Vantage` api. I am having problem working with spaced keys in a multi level `JSON` output.

JSON result:

```
{
"Time Series (1min)": {
    "2018-01-01 05:00:00": {
        "1. open": "10437.3000",
        "2. high": "10438.6500",
        "3. low": "10431.5000",
        "4. close": "10434.8000",
        "5. volume": "0"
    }
}
}
```

Corresponding Script to display data:

```
<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=response["Time Series (1min)"][0]["2018-01-01 05:00:00"]["4. close"];
//to display data in <div id="demo"></div>
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=NIFTY&interval=1min&outputsize=compact&apikey=NBRUZVG7R6SP321P", true);
xhttp.send();
</script>
```

Comment: Try removing `[0]`. You are accounting for the spaced keys correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time Series (1min)` is not array and remove `[0]`

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=response["Time Series (1min)"]["2018-01-01 05:00:00"]["4. close"];
```

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't help.
I get this: 

    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2018-01-01 05:00:00' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: I have just tested it. Refresh the script with Ctrl+F5.

Comment: Yes. I got it now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[`JSON.parse` accepts reviver function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Examples) that can be used to filter/edit/find the key value pairs:

```js
j = '{"Time Series (1min)":{"2018-01-01 05:00:00":{"1. open":"10437.3000","2. high":"10438.6500","3. low":"10431.5000","4. close":"10434.8000","5. volume":"0"}}}'

JSON.parse(j, function(key, value) { 
    if (key[0] == 4) console.log(key, value) 
})
```